# PHP SQLITE Full Text Search

Tags: php, sqlite

I have written an sqlite full text search which i am doing something wrong. If i type in my search "Puma Adidas" i want to search both words in the column MAKE.

At the moment it will only display one word if it exactly matches the search word. I just cannot figure out what i have missed, could i have some assistance please?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="SEARCH">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$search_string = $_GET['SEARCH'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE MAKE IN('$search_string') AND VISIBLE='YES' ORDER BY DATE DESC");
```

I did change the PHP code to this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE MAKE LIKE ('%$search_string%') AND VISIBLE='YES' ORDER BY DATE DESC");
```

But it still does not work unfortunately, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LIKE, not IN.  IN is used for a different purpose.

```
$search_string = $_GET['SEARCH'];

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE MAKE LIKE '$search_string') AND VISIBLE='YES' ORDER BY DATE DESC");
```

Check the syntax for the LIKE statement; you'll need to surround your search string with percent signs if you want to search the entire field for the search term.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work, the LIKE command allows me to search the first word but i want the results to show all words which are searched for which are separated by a space.

Comment: Then you need a genuine Full Text Search.  It will be difficult to do that with SQL; you would have to split the words, and do a search on each one.

Comment: is a full text search difficult to do or are there any alternatives which get me half way there as a compromise?

Comment: If you're willing to accept a search phrase instead of a list of words, you can do it with LIKE.  Otherwise, you'll need something like Lucene.  Don't forget: you'll need the percent signs if you decide to use LIKE.

Comment: Actually, SQLite has [built-in full-text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Comment: @CL. I wouldn't exactly call an extension a built-in, but there you go.